# Google Sheet Lock Data On closure of Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to design an app script for Google Sheets which protects the data upto last row when the sheet is closed.

E.g. If I am working on the sheet and data is till Row No. 100 then, when I close the sheet data upto Row 100 should be protected and locked for all users except the sheet owner.

Any help on above will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What’s the meaning of `when I close the sheet data upto Row 100`?

Comment: Row No. 100 is just an example, I mean to say than when a user closes the sheet, then script should identify the last row number having data and then should apply protection till that row number.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If `when a user closes the sheet` means that it is to close the browser tab, unfortunately, in the current stage, there is no trigger for this situation in Google Apps Script. But, if I misunderstood `when a user closes the sheet`, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in that case is it possible to use the trigger of opening the sheet?

Comment: @Edyphant `onOpen` trigger can be used, but what would be the point of it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `in that case is it possible to use the trigger of opening the sheet?`, it seems that an answer has already been commented. In this case, I would like to respect the discussion. It will resolve your issue.

Comment: @ Tanaike the answer is very helpful but it covers the trigger to be used not the full script am looking for a script to do this .....

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that you want the sample script. For this, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to protect from the 1st row to the last row in the existing data range, when the sheet is closed.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If when a user `closes the sheet` means that it is to close the browser tab, unfortunately, in the current stage, there is no trigger for this situation in Google Apps Script.

From your following reply,

> in that case is it possible to use the trigger of opening the sheet?

In this case, OnOpen trigger can be used. But, in your situation, I think that it is required to use the installable OnOpen trigger. Because the range is required to be protected.

And, from your following reply,

> it covers the trigger to be used not the full script am looking for a script to do this

I understood that you want the sample script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, [please install OnOpen trigger to the function `installedOnOpen`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). When you use this script, please set `sheetNames` and reopen the Spreadsheet. By this, the script is run.

```js
function installedOnOpen(e) {
  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1"]; // Please set the sheet names you want to protect.
  const sheets = e.source.getSheets().filter(s => sheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
  if (sheets.length == 0) return;
  sheets.forEach(s => {
    const p = s.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    if (p.length > 0) {
      p.forEach(pp => pp.remove());
    }
    const lastRow = s.getLastRow();
    if (lastRow != 0) {
      const newProtect = s.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, s.getMaxColumns()).protect();
      newProtect.removeEditors(newProtect.getEditors());
      if (newProtect.canDomainEdit()) newProtect.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, for the sheets of `sheetNames`, the 1st row to the last row in the existing data range is protected.
- If you want to run this script for all sheets in the Spreadsheet, please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```
      const sheetNames = ["Sheet1"]; // Please set the sheet names you want to protect.
      const sheets = e.source.getSheets().filter(s => sheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const sheets = e.source.getSheets();
    ```
- In this sample script, all columns are protected. If you want to protect only data range, please modify `const newProtect = s.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, s.getMaxColumns()).protect();` to `const newProtect = s.getDataRange().protect();`.

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: @ Tanaike Thanks a lot for the perfect solution, it works as expected and special thanks for such an easy step by step guide. On testing the script I am facing one issue, when I am applying formula in any column (arrayformula) it gets expanded to the entire range and in this case as there is data in the form of formula result the range will be locked. Is there any way to exclude columns having formulas to consider last row with data or can we customise the columns to be checked for data to find the last row?